# no_script_filename configuration in symfony 2

Tags: .htaccess, symfony

we need to config something as no_script_name in symfony1.4 but do it in symfony 2 to "On".
We look for this var but don't find the word in the project.

Can we configure that don't show app.php in symfony 2?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Symfony doesn't show it by default.

Comment: Ok nucleartux, thanks. We test it and works fine. Previusly we set mod_rewrite to On.